# Users who work in same department

Tags: sql, compare, user-input

Need to show the `Last_names` from the `Employees` which work in the same department like `Last_name`

How can I do that?

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = DEPARTMENTID(&LAST_NAME)
```

That's how I tried it. Maybe it works with joins but I have literally no idea...
Can anyone help??

My tables:

- Empoyees (Emp_ID, LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID)
- Departments (DEPARTMENT_ID, LOCATION)

Should look like (exampl Lastname "King")

```
| LAST_NAME | DEPARTMENT_ID |
| Mueller   | 20            |
| Bach      | 20            |
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: tried as good as possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a sub-query that returns the department id(s) for the employee(s) with that last name. Do `IN` to get the rest of the employees from same department(s).

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN (select DEPARTMENT_ID
                        FROM EMPLOYEES
                        WHERE LAST_NAME = &LAST_NAME)
```

Depending on which dbms you're using, a `JOIN` version may have better performance:

```
SELECT e1.LAST_NAME, e1.DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES e1
JOIN (select DEPARTMENT_ID
      FROM EMPLOYEES
      WHERE LAST_NAME = &LAST_NAME) e2
    ON e1.DEPARTMENT_ID = e2.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I added 2 single quotes (`'`) and now it worked.

```
SELECT LAST_NAME, DEPARTMENT_ID
FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID IN (select DEPARTMENT_ID
                        FROM EMPLOYEES
                        WHERE LAST_NAME = '&LAST_NAME')
```